# I have gone through many articles but still Getting HTTP Error 500.19 while deploying .net mvc application in local iis in windows 10 environment

Tags: asp.net-mvc, windows-10, iis-10

When I run the application using IIS Express then it works perfectly fine. The issue arises only when I deploy that in local IIS.
Please see the attached screenshot for the error.

[image: First error when deploy in local iis]

To fix this issue, I modified this part shown below:

[image: Tried this one to fix the above issue]

After doing all these, now getting below error shown in screenshot:

[image]

Can anyone please suggest me how to resolve this issue. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/websocket#appcmdexe It says clearly that this setting can only be made in applicationHost.config.

Comment: Check folder permissions where project files are placed.

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen this in applicationhost.config?  . I can get it work if I just allow the override.

In some case, it will return same error if I put it into site/directory/web.config.
But it will work if I put it into the site's web.config `<location="directory">` section.